# Booktabs table with multirows: alternative to vertical rules?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, booktabs

I am trying to format a booktabs table with multirow content. I am aware that vertical rules go against the booktabs style. However, in this table, it seems to me that some kind of vertical guide would help parsing across multiple rows. So I came up with huge curly brackets. My code and a figure of the current table is below. Is there a better (and nicer) way to aid parsing in this table - an alternative to what I have done below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,booktabs,array, multirow, rotating}

% For the huge curly brackets
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vastt}{\bBigg@{4.3}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vasttt}{\bBigg@{5.4}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vastttt}{\bBigg@{9.6}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htb]

\caption{\textbf{Title of the table}}\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Charac1}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Characteristics II}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Thing1}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Thing2}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Thing3}}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}

& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Subthing1}} 
&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Subthing2}} & & &\\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\pi_{XXX}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{None}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}

&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}c}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2} 

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\eta_{XX}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5em]{{\Vast\}}Something here}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}c}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\zeta_{XXX}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}


\multicolumn{1}{l}{XX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\epsilon$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-3}{*}[1.4em]{{\Vastt\}}Something}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.7em]{{\Vast\}}Something else}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_{XX}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Something else}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\epsilon_{XXX}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\alpha$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-3}{*}[1.1em] {{\Vastt\}}Something}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-7}{*}[3em]{{\Vastttt\}} Thing1+Thing3)}}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}c}{\multirow{-7}{*}[1.5em]{\textit{Something else}}} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$XYZ=1$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{XXXX}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$XYZ_{AB}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5em]{{\Vast\}}Attribute}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-4}{*}[1.6em]{{\Vasttt\}}Something else}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5em]{{\Vast\}}Things (thing1 \& thing2)}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5em]{\textit{Something more}}}\\
\midrule
 \end{tabular}
 \\
\footnotesize{\textbf Some footnote}
\end{sidewaystable}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Currently the output looks thus:
[image: Multirow booktabs table]

I am running up against a blank wall on ideas. Thanks for any guidance on this.

```
--------EDIT with a somewhat cleaner-looking solution----------------
```

Thanks to guidance from @ChrisS, @Werner and @cfr in the comments below, I coded a small redesign to the table, and it definitely looks much cleaner - even without the vertical rules. Code and final table below for reference (this was for [an article here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/16/31)):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,booktabs,array, multirow,rotating}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vastt}{\bBigg@{4.3}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vasttt}{\bBigg@{5.4}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vastttt}{\bBigg@{9.6}}
\makeatother

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htb]
\renewcommand\thetable{2}
\caption{\textbf{Summary of the modeling approaches included in the evaluation}}\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Model}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Ensemble Characteristics}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Output}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Paradigm}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{R Package}}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}

& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Tuning parameter}} 
&  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Model Space Construction}} & & &\\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{l}{ENC}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{ENC}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{None}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Influential variables}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}c}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-4} 

\multicolumn{1}{l}{PS}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{MB}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Influential variables}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}c}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{LS}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{ENC}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Inclusion probabilities}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{SS}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Lambda$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-3}{*}[1.2em]{{\Vastt\}}Subsampling}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Inclusion probabilities}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-4}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{PR}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{MB}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Influential variables}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{LR}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\lambda_{ENC}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Inclusion probabilities}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{SR}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Lambda$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-3}{*}[1.2em] {{\Vastt\}}Resampling}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Inclusion probabilities}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-7}{*}[3em]{{\Vastttt\}} Frequentist ($l_{1}, l_{2}$ penalties)}}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}c}{\multirow{-7}{*}[1.7em]{\textit{quadrupen, glmnet}}} \\\cmidrule(lr){1-6}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{BMA}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$EMS=1$}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Inclusion probabilities}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}
&\multicolumn{1}{>{}l}{}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{BMAC}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$EMS_{CV}$}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5em]{{\Vast\}}MCMC}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Inclusion probabilities}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5em]{{\Vast\}}Bayesian (Spike \& slab prior)}}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.2em]{\textit{BoomSpikeSlab}}}\\ 
\midrule
 \end{tabular}
\footnotesize{\textbf{ENC:} The baseline penalized regression model. Elastic net with $\lambda_{optimal} =\lambda_{ENC}$ derived from cross-validation (CV), \textbf{Ensembles based on 100 subsamples:} \textbf{PS:} Meinshausen \& B{\"u}hlmann's algorithm with a single $\lambda_{optimal} = \lambda_{MB}$ selected to minimize the expected number of false positives, \textbf{LS:} Single $\lambda_{optimal} = \lambda_{ENC}$ with no variable selection, \textbf{SS:} Stability selection across the entire 100 $\lambda \in \Lambda$ grid with no variable selection, \textbf{Ensembles based on 100 resamples: }\textbf{PR, LR, SR:} Identical to PS, PR and LR, respectively, with model space constructed through resampling. \textbf{BMA:} Bayesian model averaging with expected model size ($EMS$) = 1, \textbf{BMAC:} BMA with EMS determined by CV ($EMS_{CV}$).}
\end{sidewaystable}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks now:
[image: (Not bad at all. :-)]

Comment: Since there is no strict hierarchy, I think your current way is clearest, but you could also just repeat the items on each row.

Comment: The grouping across columns doesn't seem hierarchical. Does `Things (thing1 & thing2)` brace the same scope as `Attribute`?

Comment: @Werner Yes, they do. Do you think there is a way to arrange this better?

Comment: @ChrisS Thanks, I did try repeating the items. Somehow the table starts to look redundant. :/

Comment: I would either (1) rethink the way you are presenting data, or (2) not use `booktabs` in this case so that you can use vertical rules. That will be less unclear, I think. (1) first choice. (2) if (1) isn't an option.

Comment: @Ariel: `Thing3` seems superfluous...

Comment: @Werner Great point, thanks! I am collapsing Thing2 and Thing3 together into a single column.

Comment: @cfr - Unfortunately, this is for a journal that enforces booktabs (and for good reasons, I might say). If you are curious this is table 2 here: http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/s12859-015-0467-6.pdf The table looks terrible in the proof typeset version they have now sent me because they haven't used the trimming options in `cmidrule` and the midrules overflow beyond the curly brackets. The table had colours earlier but they made me rip out the colours: http://i.imgur.com/rZMgQrV.png  I came here because I was pretty much out of ideas. :)

Comment: Generally, `booktabs` produces clearer tables. I just don't think it does here. So I disagree that it is a good policy even though I think most tables should use it.

Comment: @cfr What do you think? First thing i thought looking at the material was *TikZ*. You have a lot of tikzperience, maybe you can provide an alternative solution?

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not sure. Without really understanding the job the presentation needs to do, it is difficult to suggest coherent ways of restructuring it. The modified version added in the edit is reasonably clear, although I'd omit most of the horizontal lines, I think. I don't know how important the column headings are. If that information can be conveyed implicitly (i.e. will be obvious to the readers anyway), a tree or schema might work better. But if the information is essential, maybe a table is the best option. It would help if the subsampling/resampling/etc. could be outside the table.

Comment: @cfr Should we make the edit above a cw-answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Not sure.... Maybe that would be good. I'll also see if I can create a couple of possibilities which might be useful, but a cw answer would at least ensure something usable if those turn out to be inapplicable. But maybe we should see what the OP thinks?

Comment: @Johannes_B I really think that answer is better than what I can come up with in TikZ. Maybe somebody else will do better...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a rather different way of presenting the information which may or may not be suitable. Unlike the modified table, this fits within the confines of the text area. (The other produces overfull boxes.)

[image: tree presentation]

This is essentially a `forest` tree, as `justtrees` is an experimental wrapper for `forest`. This may make it unacceptable for submission purposes, but you can include the code, if necessary, and load `forest` directly instead. There is a copy of `justtrees.sty` around somewhere but ask me for version 0.04 if you actually want to try this out.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,lmodern,justtrees}% version 0.04 of justtrees
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \caption{\textbf{Summary of the modeling approaches included in the evaluation}}\label{fig2}% it would be better to use \captionsetup to format captions globally
  \begin{center}
    \begin{justtree}{
        right justifiers,
        for tree={
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          just format={font=\bfseries},
          l sep+=5pt,
          s sep+=5pt,
          if n children=3{
            calign child=2,
            calign=child
          }{},
          if level=3{font=\itshape}{},
          if level=5{math content}{},
        },
      }
      [Modelling Approaches,
        [{Frequentist ($l_{1}, l_{2}$ penalties)}, just=Paradigm
          [{quadrupen, glmnet}, just=R Package
            [None, just=Model Space Construction
              [\lambda_{ENC}
                [ENC,
                tikz={
                  \draw (.south) |- ($(.south)!1/2!(iv2.south) - (10pt,35pt)$) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,-15pt) coordinate (b) ++(10pt,0) node (iv) [anchor=north] {Influential variables};
                  \draw (!>.south) |- ([xshift=10pt, yshift=10pt]a) -- ([xshift=10pt]b);
                  \draw (iv2.south) |- ([xshift=20pt]a) -- ([xshift=20pt]b);
                  \node [anchor=mid west, justifier format] at (right just 2.mid west |- iv.mid) {Output};
                }
                ]
              ]
            ]
            [Subsampling
              [\lambda_{MB}
                [PS
                ]
              ]
              [\lambda_{ENC}
                [LS,
                tikz={
                  \draw (.south) |- ($(.south)!1/2!(ip2.south) - (25pt,25pt)$) coordinate (c) -- ++(0,-25pt) coordinate (d) ++(25pt,0) node (ip) [anchor=north] {Inclusion probabilities};
                  \draw (!>.south) |- ([xshift=10pt, yshift=10pt]c) -- ([xshift=10pt]d);
                  \draw (!>>>.south) |- ([xshift=20pt, yshift=20pt]c) -- ([xshift=20pt]d);
                  \draw (!>>>>.south) |- ([xshift=30pt, yshift=10pt]c) -- ([xshift=30pt]d);
                  \draw (!>>>>>.south) |- ([xshift=40pt]c) -- ([xshift=40pt]d);
                  \draw (ip2.south) |- ([xshift=50pt,yshift=-10pt]c) -- ([xshift=50pt]d);
                }
                ]
              ]
              [\Lambda
                [SS
                ]
              ]
            ]
            [Resampling
              [\lambda_{MB}
                [PR, name=iv2
                ]
              ]
              [\lambda_{ENC}
                [LR
                ]
              ]
              [\Lambda
                [SR
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
        [Bayesian (Spike \& slab prior)
          [BoomSpikeSlab
            [MCMC
              [{EMS=1}
                [BMA, just=Model
                ]
              ]
              [EMS_{CV}, just=Tuning parameter
                [BMAC, name=ip2,
                tikz={
                  \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick]  (right just 4.north east) +(5pt,0) coordinate (e) -- (e |- right just 5.south) node [midway, right, xshift=5pt, justifier format, align=left] {Ensemble\\Characteristics};
                }
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{justtree}
  \end{center}
  \footnotesize% note that this is a switch - it does not take an argument
  \textbf{ENC:} The baseline penalized regression model. Elastic net with $\lambda_{optimal} =\lambda_{ENC}$ derived from cross-validation (CV), \textbf{Ensembles based on 100 subsamples:} \textbf{PS:} Meinshausen \& B{\"u}hlmann's algorithm with a single $\lambda_{optimal} = \lambda_{MB}$ selected to minimize the expected number of false positives, \textbf{LS:} Single $\lambda_{optimal} = \lambda_{ENC}$ with no variable selection, \textbf{SS:} Stability selection across the entire 100 $\lambda \in \Lambda$ grid with no variable selection, \textbf{Ensembles based on 100 resamples: }\textbf{PR, LR, SR:} Identical to PS, PR and LR, respectively, with model space constructed through resampling. \textbf{BMA:} Bayesian model averaging with expected model size ($EMS$) = 1, \textbf{BMAC:} BMA with EMS determined by CV ($EMS_{CV}$).
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this looks very good.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks. I gave up once but then decided to have another go. It can out better than I feared :).

Comment: Wow - this is beautiful. Thank you @Johannes_B for reviving this question and to cfr for posting such an inspired answer. I wish I could go back in time and resubmit this figure to the journal (okay, not really, I am glad the paper's done, but this figure is a nice alternative way to present the same information with no redundancy. Will keep this mind for the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ariel Probably just as well. My code is rather experimental - I'm not sure that would go down well with a journal! (But I'm trying to improve it by finding interesting questions to try it out on, and this came out better than I expected.) Glad you like it - may come in useful another time....